# Binding to IPv6 address not available since kernel does not support IPv6

Tags: mongodb, ipv6, systemctl

Trying to autostart mongodb , but does not work

$ sudo systemctl status mongod.service -l
● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual

Nov 03 00:28:08 xxxxx systemd[1]: mongod.service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Nov 03 00:28:13 xxxx systemd[1]: mongod.service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.

$ sudo systemd-analyze verify /usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service
Binding to IPv6 address not available since kernel does not support IPv6.

Comment: Much modern software requires IPv6, and soon everything will require it. Contact your system administrator, as your system is in a very broken state.

Answer (score 0):

we had same file under `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service`  and `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`
Removed the file `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service`
And run the `systemctl disable mongod`
`systemctl enable  mongod`
`systemctl start  mongod`